# Can't visualize "Separable space" and Why we need "Separable space".

Tags: general-topology

I am a beginner in Topology and didn't understand the "Separable space" correctly.  I understand that there exist a countable dense subset in $X$. But the problem is ... I am unable to make a mental picture of this definition. And why we need separable Space.

Comment: The basic example of a separable space would be the real numbers.  Any real number can be approximated by a sequence of rational numbers (and the rational numbers are countable).  There are some nice properties that come from being separable, for example, every collection of disjoint open sets is countable in a separable space (because every such open set contains at least one point of the countable dense subset).

Comment: That means .. A space is separable if every element can be approximated by some sequence of elements of $X$. Am i right..

Comment: Not quite, every element of $X$ can be approximated by elements of $X$ (namely itself).  The difference is that elements of $X$ can be approximated by elements of a fixed countable subset of $X$.

Comment: It is worth-while to have an example of an inseparable space at hand. Trivially, we can take $\Bbb R$ with discrete topology. Another one is the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29). Inseparable spaces are "too big" in some sense (though that does not hold literally)